# about html textarea's post value

Tags: php, html, xhtml, textarea

text file in window, each line end with \r\n, in unix, each line end with \n.
Does textarea's post value follow this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a modified function I've used from php.net commetns to replace \n and \r into one 
 {or whatever you pass in}

```
function replaceNewLines($string,$replacement='<br />') 
{ 
    return preg_replace("/(\r\n)+|(\n|\r)+/", $replacement, $string); 
} 

$string = "this is \n\n\n a String with many \n\n\r\r returns!"; 

$string = replaceNewLines($string,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple: yes

Usually you just want to replace `\n` by `<br />` and that does the trick.

Comment: You only use that replace when placing the result of a post from a textarea in HTML output.  However you are correct browser maintain the client platforms newline character sequence.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows with Opera, Firefox and IE7 it ends the text lines with \r\n. I presume in Unix will be only \n, but don't have a system to test now.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter when typing in a textarea, it creates just a \n.

If you want to then display the data (formatted with line breaks) on a page, you need to to a str_replace on the text from your textarea to replace the \n's.

Answer (score 0):

If processing is done by php there is a php function called **nl2br** that will do the trick. It takes two argument, first is your string, second is a bool true for xhtml and false for html.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
echo nl2br("Welcome\r\nThis is my HTML document", false);
?>
```

The above example will output (first is xhtml, second plain html):

```
foo isn't<br />
 bar

Welcome<br>
This is my HTML document
```